# Instagram API fetch all images by tag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Playing with instagram tags API I have faced with a trouble. The trouble is instagram API doesn't send me all photos that is has. For example I use my application (with pagination and count parameter of course) or http://iconosquare.com/tag/ site, but it returns only 25 photos for a certain tag. Android instagram application returns 26 ones! And it's really 26 photos with a tag there - instagram API simply doesn't send me a information about that 26th photo. What's I'm doing wrong?
This photo really has that hash-tag and I can see it right now with my own eyes. Count parameter set to 30.

Another question is why API returns me wrong photo count when i'm taking a info about tag? For ex. for the previous tag it always returnes number 45 as photos count whether I added or removed any tag from photo.